# Ubuntu hangs on purple boot screen 17.04

Tags: boot, 17.04

I was attempting to setup Chrome remote desktop using the code function and i had just put the code in my chrome book and i wait a few seconds, look back at my PC and the loading bar doesn't move, i reboot and it starts hanging on purple screen! Please help!

(Holding shift doesn't work too and neither does caps lock or num lock activate the keyboard light)
On 17.04

Comment: Are you seeing the GRUB menu? Can you get to recovery mode, root access?

Comment: nope, as I said before holding shift does nothing

Comment: If you have a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, I can tell you how to do a file system check on your boot drive. Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realised that earlier in that day a update errored, I didnt think much of it but it turned out I missed a important system upgrade! After some help IRL (and flashing a USB stick) I was able to get it to load by redoing my grub  (Software raid on boot is hard :/) and my nvidia drivers decided top b*tch around alot. All fixed now and of you have this issue then I reccomend following these steps:
 1. Shutdown PC ang go into bios, activate Intergrated graphics
 2. Load the SAME VERSION YOU HAVE onto a USB stick and boot off it
 3. Mount your raid arrays to something like /mnt and /mnt/boot (i have raid 1 for boot and raid 6 for root, just to be clear)
 4. chroot into them
 5. Run all updates you can, you may need to re-config your grub too
 6. Reboot and go back to PCIE graphics then enter your normal system

Answer (score 0):

Unplug all other usb devices with the exception of the keyboard. Some low-end usb chargers and hubs could be causing issues.

Comment: I dont think that that could be the issue, I didnt change anything there...

Comment: This is not an answer, but rather a question/comment. Please make it into a comment on the original question. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have enough rep to add a comment to the main post :(